# Using env variables in logstash config

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kubernetes-helm

I have configured to run logstash as a sidecar and push the data to es after capturing any change from the db. I have added variables that will be used by logstash image from my service. But somehow it is not able to capture those env variables

JDBC input plugin in logstash config

```
jdbc {
    jdbc_driver_library => "/usr/share/logstash/mysql-connector-java-8.0.22.jar"
    jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://${MYSQL_HOST}/<DB_NAME>"
    jdbc_user => "${MYSQL_USER}"
    jdbc_password => "${MYSQL_PASSWORD}"
.
.
.
```

My deployment.yaml of the service that is using the above logstash config. I am

```
- name: logstash-sidecar
  image: <Logstash image name here>
  imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
  securityContext:
     runAsNonRoot: true
     runAsUser: 1001
env:
            - name: MYSQL_HOST
              value: {{ .Values.datastore.host }}
            - name: MYSQL_USER
              value: {{ .Values.datastore.user | quote }}
            - name: ES_HOST
              value: {{ .Values.logstash.es.host }}
            - name: MYSQL_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: db-secret
                  key: db_password_key
```

- Please note here that logstash configurations is a totally new service and I am using the image of that service in a new service where I want to run it as side-car.
- Please ignore the indentation part. That is correct its just here it was not parsed well

I tried deploying the changes but logstash was not able to run in sidecar as it was not able to understand any of the env variables

Comment: Is your issue just that the logstash configuration isn't recognizing `$MYSQL_HOST`?  The Kubernetes/Helm fragment looks correct to me (up to indentation – this is quite important, and can be subtle in Helm).

Comment: This was resolved. The issue here was, I was using volume mounts in my image and that doesn't work when we are pushing the image. Used copy in my docker file instead of mount and this is now working, it is able to consume the env variables

Answer (score 0):

The [code](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-integration-jdbc/blob/06436fd0e8cca5375ba9547573be536b7db03072/lib/logstash/plugin_mixins/jdbc/jdbc.rb#L123) does not sprintf jdbc_connection_string, it is just passed as-is to the [sequel](https://sequel.jeremyevans.net/) library. Nor does [it](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-integration-jdbc/blob/06436fd0e8cca5375ba9547573be536b7db03072/lib/logstash/plugin_mixins/jdbc/common.rb#L17) sprintf jdbc_user or jdbc_password so those cannot use environment variables either.